# Upload word document to create a file download (PHP)

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am doing a school project where students can upload study notes to help other students. I have created the ability to upload word/pages files but I want to enable that once the file is uploaded, other users can click on that file and it will download for them.

Not really sure what code to put.. (This is upload.php)

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $name     = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $error    = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $size     = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $ext      = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        switch ($error) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                $valid = true;
                //validate file extensions
                if ( !in_array($ext, array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif', 'docx', 'mp3')) ) {
                    $valid = false;
                    $response = 'Invalid file extension.';
                }
```

And this is where the files go (files.php)

```
<?php
        //scan "uploads" folder and display them accordingly
       $folder = "uploads";
       $results = scandir('uploads');
       foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

        if (is_file($folder . '/' . $result)) {
            echo '
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="'.$folder . '/' . $result.'" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption">
                        <p><a href="remove.php?name='.$result.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button">Remove</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
       }
       ?>
```

Cheers!

Comment: If you want to download a file, you simply just put the link of the file and it will automatically do it for you. :) ie: `header("Location: http://example.com/example.docx"); exit();`

Comment: or, in addition to @KyleE4K comment, optionally you can also add it on a `<a>` tag. `<a href="/upload/yourfile.docx" target="_blank">yourfile.docx</a>`

Comment: @catzilla - where abouts in the code?

Comment: @blakeusmate, I posted an answer, you can try it..

Comment: @KyleE4K - where abouts in the code do i put this? and it's localhosted too so what do I do? cheers

Comment: Check the answer, that is a perfect example on how to do this - Links will be seen on the front-end and when you click them, it will start a download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a link where other users can download the files that are uploaded, try adding an `<a>` tag with the link of the file in it:

```
<?php
  //scan "uploads" folder and display them accordingly
  $folder = "uploads";
  $results = scandir('uploads');
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

    if (is_file($folder . '/' . $result)) {
      $file = $folder.'/'.$result;
      echo '<a href="{$file}" target="_blank">{$result}</a><br/>';
      //other codes
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: tried this .. the file says ($result) go to click on it and it takes me to a location that doesn't exist

Comment: then based on your file directory structure, you should align or correct the location of the file so that the link would be correct. maybe can you share to us the directory structure of your project?

Comment: Inspect the element of the `<a>` tag (front end) and view the `file path`, check if it *correctly* corresponds to your file server path.